# html form input to get path folder information

Tags: javascript, php, html

In PHP We can do like this to view files inside a folder:

```
$dir    = '/var/www/';
$files1 = scandir($dir, 1);
print_r($files1);
```

But I want $dir depends on user input on html front end, so user may get files inside folder they choose.

Comment: You would need to make use of AJAX to `POST` the user's decision as a variable that gets piped out to the PHP code. See [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php).

Comment: @ObsidianAge, you don't need AJAX to perform a `POST`!

Comment: You don't *need* it, but considering the HTML is not provided, you can't be sure there's a `<form>` that's set up correctly. And if you want to do it without a page refresh you need AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

Front End
To accept the path you can use either **input type="text" or input type="file"**

```
<?php
 if(isset($_REQUEST["dir_path"]))
 {
    $dir=$_REQUEST["dir_path"];//path specified in the html form
    $files1 = scandir($dir, 1);

    print_r($files1);
 }
?>
```

Comment: I know how to receive in the back-end. What i need is how to post 'dir-path' in front-end.